# Анализ алгоритмов

Tags: алгоритм

Читаю в книге Кормен: Алгоритмы построение и анализ анализ алгоритмов

[image]

При условии, что

```
for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++)  будет n-1 повторов проверки условия цикла
```

При условии, что

```
for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) будет n-2 повторов проверки условия цикла
```

Откуда берется n повторов?

Comment: то есть, почему не `n-1` и `n-2`,  а везде n? При больших n разница невелика, поэтому и отбрасывают

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, если я правильно понял, то тут для конкретного случая описывают количичество повторов каждой элементарной операции. И мне не понятно, почему условие цикла for проверяется n раз, оно же проверяется n-1 раз при условии что, j от 2 до j <= n, и n-2 при условии, что j от 2 до j < n.

И воообще на будущее for = 2 to n, в записях такого вида имеется в виду, что до n включительно или нет

Comment: >  for = 2 to n

да, здесь включительно.

С n. Если считать точно, то сложность будет что то вида `(n-1)(a+(n-2))` где а - это сложность внутри первого цикла, не включенная в второй. Можно раскрыть скобки и получить что то вида `n^2 - (3+a)n + 2`. Потом вспомнить курс высшей математики, где доводиться, что при больших значениях n можно смотреть только на старшую степень. (здесь кроется загвозда. Если a сильно большое по сравнению с n, то игнорировать не нужно, на это натыкаются "специалисты" по тестированию скорости, когда их измерение времени тратит больше времени чем код)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин, люди, вы о чем? Какая сложность? Здесь расписывается количество операций каждой инструкции. Сколько раз выполнится строчка for в данном случае:

```
n = 0
for i = 2 to n:
    print i
```

Ни разу? А вы уверены? Ни разу не выполнится print, а условие хотя бы раз, но проверяться будет: первое выполнение сделает i равным 2 и проверит, что i больше n. Т.к. оно будет большим (т.к. 2 > 0), то остальное выполняться не будет. Вот и получается - for здесь выполнится один раз, а print ни разу.

UPD: про саму задачу забыл написать

```
for j = 2 to n

Первый проход - j = 2, j <= n, поэтому выполняем тело цикла
Второй проход - j = 3, j <= n, поэтому выполняем тело цикла
...
n-1 проход - j = n, j <= n, поэтому выполняем тело цикла
n проход - j = n + 1, j > n, поэтому тело цикла не выполняем
```

Вот и получается - тело цикла было выполнено n-1 раз, а сама инструкция for была выполнена n раз, причем последнее выполнение просто проверяет, что цикл больше выполнять не надо.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто, есть три определения сложности алгоритма:

1. Точная.
2. В худшем случае.
3. В лучшем случае.

Обычно используется второй вариант, и в нём можно отбрасывать несущественные значения.

Прочтите замечательную статью на хабре:

**Введение в анализ сложности алгоритмов**

[часть 1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196560/)

[часть 2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/195482/)

[часть 3](http://habrahabr.ru/post/195996/)

[часть 4](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196226/)